# How can one expand the messages of a conversation in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook.com

How can one expand the messages of a conversation in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

For example, in Gmail one can click on:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](https://redd.it/1afy1wz) by Reddit user [xorbe](https://www.reddit.com/user/xorbe):

> View tab -> Expand Conversation

I confirm it works.

[image]